# AS3 class instances names

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I really wonder. I made a MovieClip class Apple, I wrote a function that creates a new instance with a name "apple". Each time a new instance is pushed into an Array "apples". I call the function 5 times and I get 5 apples. I can manipulate them by calling them i.e. apples[0]. And when I trace my array I see 5 [object Apple] things. So maybe I don't really understand the structure of AS3 objects but **shouldn't each object have a name?**

When I set apple.name and get an array with 5 different names, I can't manipulate objects by names like *apple1.x = 10*. **How does computer know which apple is where if each has own coordinates? Is the only way to call them: apples[0]-apples[4]? And if I create a code that should be same for all apples, how should I address the function, to "this"?** Cause when I write class code I don't have any names yet...

For example, if I want to make Apple class a picture(MovieClip) that can be dragged, create any number of apples, up to a million, I can't possibly add *apples[0].addEventListener, apples[1].addEventListener ... apples[1000000].addEventListener* to the code. **How do I make it global?**

I'm asking cause when I'm directly coding for a specific instance, it has a name and I know exactly what am I addressing. And working with a class and making many objects I kinda don't... Sorry, I'm green

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need names to be able to access and manipulate your instances.

You can do something like this:

```
var apples:Array = new Array();

for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var apple:Apple = new Apple();
    apples.push(apple);
    apple.x = Math.random() * 500;
    apple.y = Math.random() * 500;
    addChild(apple);
    apple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onAppleClick);

}

function onAppleClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var ind:int = apples.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
    var apple:Apple = apples[ind];
    trace(ind);
    apples[ind].visible = false;
    //or 
    //apple.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good example, to get the OP rolling.  @SherWood, the "name" property of all DisplayObject instances, is not the same as the variable name in your script before compilation.  In your example storing the objects in an array, AS3 knows where the objects are and maintains a reference to them through your array.  Say array is at address 0 and each object is 20 bytes, object one is at 0, object two is then at address 20, object three at address 40 (usually this kind of thing is discussed with C but the theory still applies to AS3).  There are as shown here ways to get the var.

Comment: Also good to note, if you write a method within a class (say you write a method in the Apple class) then "this" means the current instance, so instead of writing a bunch of code "outside" of the instances that acts upon them you can encapsulate that code into methods within the Class definition.

Comment: Very nice and simple, thanks a bunch! I'll try and tell you if it worked. Also, this is kinda a way to get a specific apple from the swarm? If I want to click one of them and instead of visible apply marryMe function, and change ringPutOn = true, and change color to pink, and stop it from doing what other apples do, it will be special, is it fine? (what a perv XD) It wont change the whole class? Or you rather recommend to make a new class that would represent a wife-apple and change clicked one for new one?

Answer (score 3):

The same problem, huh? :)

For example `Apple extends Sprite` and inherits property `name`.

It's public, this means that you can change its name.

```
var apple:Apple = new Apple() ;
apple.name = "MegaApple" ;
```

Also, if you add the apple to stage, you can get him via name.

```
stage.addChild(apple) ;
```

get apple back:

```
var oldApple:Apple = stage.getChildByName("MegaApple") ;
```

But that never means, that you can use apple like that:
`MegaApple.move()` -  because name of apple is supposed to be a property of apple, not a name of a variable.

Of course, you can create a lot of apples manually:

```
var apple1 = new Apple() ;
var apple2 = new Apple() ;
var apple3 = new Apple() ;
```

But if they all behave the same way, there is no point in doing. That's why you store them into array.

Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Hehe, sorry,  you left and I still had question ^_^'